# Is there a way to organize colliders?

Tags: unity, tilemap, collider

I am using a tilemap to design levels for my game in Unity.
So, naturally, I need some circle/box colliders to interact with the objects in the game.

I know that if I use a prefab for every tile, I can also attach a collider, and never have to worry to add or modift colliders. But this seems too impractical, and also if I want to modify a block of colliders, I have to do this for every single tile.

I also tried using `Tilemap Colldier 2D`, but it generates colliders for the places I don't want colliders, such as grasses that stick out from the ground tiles.

My question is, is there any neat way to organize colliders so that I can identify them by looking at their names, IDs, etc.?

Currently, I am designing only one level and anxiety builds up on me as I take a look at the colliders in a single tilemap. How can I automate or organize the colliders for my tilemap?

Comment: Have you considered using a [TilemapCollider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TilemapCollider2D.html) to manage the collisions of your map overall?

Comment: I did, but it automatically generates colliders for areas where I don't want the colliders. For instance, some grass sticking up the ground tiles.

Comment: So you [cleaned up the physics shapes for those tiles as explained in this guide](https://www.aetherpoint.com/blogpost/editing-the-unity-tilemap-collider-2d-box/), right?

Comment: Wow! I don't have such an option in the dropdown menu. Didn't know it existed. I think I am doing something wrong here.